# Google Sheets, how to address a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I create a formula as text and want to use that formula in another formula. How can I use this text as a formula in another formula?
f.e.
**K3=**importrange(C3;"DS!A1:J20000");importrange(C3;"DS!A20001:J40000");importrange(C3;"DS!A40001:J60000")

I want to use this formula in this main formula:

=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({
**K3**}))

But the output is only
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFOS7.png)